# tool for class -diagram which can show even relationship between classes for windows application

Tags: c#, .net, class, uml

I'm looking for tool - which can draw class diagram and relationship from the code (code written in C# or .net specific code only).
I tried tools like Nclass,Enterprise architecture and other tools but .. it draws class diagram without relationship between the diagrams.
need to relatioship also in class -diagram

thanks

Comment: [How to: Create UML Class Diagrams from Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657806.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best tool I have used is [ndepend](http://www.ndepend.com/). It also comes with a query language which is pretty cool.

Comment: query language means ? along with class diagram.. i need relationship between the class also.. in diagram.. can this be achieved by tool suggested.

Comment: will tool draw relationship also in class diagram.. ?

Comment: You can find code based upon criteria we used it to find code.  Like functions over 100 lines or methods that didn't meet naming standards.